# What does $set do in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I can't see the difference between using it:

```
update({"name" : "nick"}, {"$set" : {"age" : 50}})
```

and not using it;

```
update({"name" : "nick"}, {"age" : 50})
```

from the example in [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/). It's not clear to me.

Thanks for the comment but if I use `{"$set" : {"array_field" : [{'f' : 'v'}] }}` it adds `{'f' : 'v'}` to the array instead of replacing the array with `[{'f' : 'v'}]`, so why doesn't $set replace the array with the new one?

Comment: What version of MongoDB is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`update({"name" : "nick"}, {"age" : 50})` replaces **the complete object** with only `{"age" : 50}`.

Running `find({"name" : "nick" })` after running the above update would return no document found error.

Using $set would allow to update only the "age" param of the original object.

Karl Seguin's [Little Mongodb Book](https://github.com/karlseguin/the-little-mongodb-book/blob/master/en/mongodb.markdown#update-replace-versus-set) has a very good explanation about the difference between replace and set.

Comment: I felt like I needed to highlight that **not using the $set operator destroys every field not in the value object**. One time I had to restore a database from backup because I forgot about that. It was just a development database, but it could have been much worse.

Comment: But if I use {"$set" : {"array_field" : [{'f' : 'v'}] }} it adds {'f' : 'v'} to the array instead of replacing the array with [{'f' : 'v'}]

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me as expected:

```
> db.test.insert({"a":1, "b": [{"v":1, "b":1}]})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5102c75c8e48734ea1220a9c"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ { "v" : 1, "b" : 1 } ] }
> db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5102c75c8e48734ea1220a9c")}, {$set: {"b": [{"v":1}]}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5102c75c8e48734ea1220a9c"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ { "v" : 1 } ] }
```

I thought it could have been the way JS interpreted the array but it isn't, it works just dandy for me.

Can you show us the queries you are performing? Maybe a full script can replicate this behaviour?

#### Edit

I noticed your data was different so I have replicated it exactly below:

```
> db.test.insert({"a":1, "b": [{'f':'v'}]})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5102c8868e48734ea1220a9d"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ { "f" : "v" } ] }
> db.test.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("5102c8868e48734ea1220a9d")}, {$set: {"b": [{"f":"b"}]}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5102c8868e48734ea1220a9d"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ { "f" : "b" } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks. There was someone else writing to my database. Didn't know what was happening.

Comment: @nickponline If you app is distributed it could be that the atomic lock finished and then some one else came along and reset it with another process. Hmm if you expect this often you might wanna look into how to design this in a distributed manner